# Access instance variable from another class

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, class, object

I would like to access the instance variable (orders) of a class (DailyOrders) from the **init** of another, keeping in mind that the class containing the instance variable is a parent to the other. This seems to perfect use for inheritance but I couldn't get it to work. Here is the code.

```
class DailyOrders():

    PRICE_PER_DOZEN = 6.5

    def __init__(self, day):
        self.orders = []
        self.day = day

    def total_eggs(self):
        total_eggs = 0
        for order in self.orders:
            total_eggs += order.eggs
        return total_eggs

    def show_report(self):
        if self.total_eggs() < 0:
            print("No Orders")
        else:
            print(f"Summary:\nTotal Eggs Ordered: {self.total_eggs()}\n*********")
            print(f"Average Eggs Per Customer: {self.total_eggs() / len(self.orders):.0f}")


class EggOrder():

    def __init__(self, eggs=0, name=""):
        if not name:
            self.new_order()
        else:
            self.name = name
            self.eggs = eggs

        orders.append(self)

    def new_order(self):
        self.name = string_checker("Name: ")
        self.eggs = num_checker("Number of Eggs: ")

    def get_dozens(self):
        if self.eggs % 12 != 0:
            dozens = int(math.ceil(self.eggs / 12))
        else:
            dozens = self.eggs / 12
        return dozens

    def show_order(self):
        print(f"{self.name} ordered {self.eggs} eggs. The price is ${self.get_dozens() * DailyOrders.PRICE_PER_DOZEN}.")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    friday = DailyOrders("Friday")
    friday_order = EggOrder(12, "Someone")
    friday_order.show_order()
    friday.show_report()

    saturday = DailyOrders("Saturday")
    saturday_order = EggOrder(19, "Something")
    saturday_order.show_order()
    saturday.show_report()
```

I have not tried using inheritance before, but one proposed solution is to use 
`super(EggOrder, self).__init__()` but this made me provide the day, as it was going to create another instance of the DailyOrders class. I don't want this.

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just inherit and user `super` to call the parent initializer:

```
class DailyOrders:

    def __init__(self, day):
        self.orders = []
        # ...

class EggOrder(DailyOrders):

    def __init__(self, day, eggs=0, name=""):
        super().__init__(day)
        # Now self.orders is available.
```

Keep in mind that if the parent initializer receives any parameter, the child must receive it as well in order to be able to pass it.

### Not providing a day param ...

If you don't want to provide a day param you should have another class with the interface/functionality that's common to the others, and the inherit from such base class:

```
class BaseOrders:
    def __init__(self):
        self.orders = []
        # ...

class DailyOrders(BaseOrders):

    def __init__(self, day):
        super().__init__()
        # Now self.orders is available.
        self.day = day
        # ...

class EggOrder(BaseOrders):

    def __init__(self, eggs=0, name=""):
        super().__init__()
        # Now self.orders is available.
```